# RSpec superclass mismatch (Sinatra)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have several spec files for my Sinatra API. They test a Module MysuperBlog and a class API within that Module.

I have this in a RSpec config file :

```
RSpec.shared_context 'Reset class' do
    after(:each) do
        Object.send(:remove_const, :API)
    end
end
```

the spec files all have these lines of code:

```
require 'rack/test'
require 'json'
require_relative '../../../app/main.rb'

module MysuperBlog
    class API
        RSpec.describe 'An author logs in to his account', type: :request do

        include_context 'Reset class'
```

The main app file contains:

```
module MysuperBlog    
    class API < Sinatra::Base
```

Each spec succeeds but when I run `rspec` without arguments, it raises an error:

```
TypeError:
  superclass mismatch for class API
```

I guess this is caused by the module and the class being defined in each file.

How should I reorder the code so both the individual tests and the global test pass without this error?

Comment: Why are you defining your tests inside the class `MysuperBlog::API`?

Comment: That actually is the right question! I did that because I just finished learning rspec with the book "Effective testing..." that explain that defining test inside the modules provides easier access to the classes of that module. But I have remove that, now testing outside Mysuperblob::API and all is fine.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what it was suggesting. While I would never test this way it appears the recommendation was only to open the encapsulating module e.g. `module MysuperBlog; RSpec.describe API do #....`. [Example](https://github.com/rspec-3-book/book-code/blob/master/05-unit-specs/03/expense_tracker/spec/unit/app/api_spec.rb). You went one layer deeper and tried to put the tests inside the class `MysuperBlog::API`.

Comment: Maybe I should try again, but I had the same error message when puting the test in module MysuperBlog, without the class API. Anyway, removing the tests from the module altogether works fine too.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess this is caused by the module and the class being defined in each file.

The [`class` keyword](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Defining+a+class) in Ruby serves two purposes: to create a class and to re-open an existing class.

If your class has a superclass other than `Object`, it has to be given when creating the class but it can be omitted when re-opening it, e.g.: (I'm using `Array` just for demonstration purposes, you shouldn't subclass core classes in general)

```
class Foo < Array ; end

class Foo ; end         # <- works
```

Doing it the other way round raises the error you are seeing:

```
class Foo ; end

class Foo < Array ; end # <- TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Foo
```

> How should I reorder the code  [...]

I assume that you load the file which is supposed to re-open an existing class before the file which is supposed to create the class and which specifies its superclass.

If so, ensure that you load the latter first (`require` it, e.g. in your spec helper) and your problem should be solved.

---

If you don't actually want to re-open an existing class but instead attempt to re-use the same class name for different throw-away classes in your tests, you can remove the constant via [`remove_const`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Module.html#method-i-remove_const) after you're done with the class / test: (e.g. in an RSpec `after` hook)

```
class Foo < Array ; end

Object.send(:remove_const, :Foo)

class Foo < String ; end # different Foo, no error
```

This way, each `class Foo` creates a new and independent class instead of re-opening the previous one.

`Object` is used for top-level constants. For nested constants, replace `Object` with the module that actually holds the constant.

Comment: might be worth mentioning that `::API` and `::MysuperBlog::API` need not have the same superclass, as this part of the question confused me since it shows "superclass mismatch for class API" and I am unclear if "API" is `::API` or `::MysuperBlog::API`

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan. I have updated the question. I'm still not clear on this.